# A bode for disunity? Can "bode" be used this way?

Tags: meaning

I have only seen "bode" used with "bodes ill", "bodes well", "bodes no good".  Bode as omen or portent of generalities.  The word has an old Shakespearean feel to me.

I found this:

https://talkingpointsmemo.com/news/with-2024-on-her-mind-haley-suggests-dems-should-give-trump-a-break-on-impeachment

> “I don’t even think there is a basis for impeachment,” Haley told Fox
> News’ Laura Ingraham in an interview. Haley offered no qualifications
> for those claims — opting instead to suggest that impeaching her
> former boss was a bode for disunity.

Can one use bode to describe more specific predictions than good or bad?  Could I say "The smell was a bode for shrimp curry"?  Or did this person type bode by accident and mean to use a different word.

Comment: Maybe they meant "a *bid* for disunity"? "Bode" makes no sense here: it's not a noun.

Comment: Probably “about” disunity. This is a transcript, not a script, I think.

Comment: As a noun meaning *premonition, omen, augury*, the word ***bode*** is obsolete / archaic.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bode) has '**bode** (1) An omen; a foreshadowing_1380s, Geoffrey Chaucer, Parlement of Foules:
_The oule eek, that of dethe the bode bringeth_'. No caveat, but I think it needs one. The only recent hits via a Google ngram for 'a bode' I've found are for 'Bode' used prenominally (a Bode diagram / plot // representative ...) (or archaic quotes).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it may or may not be what someone actually once said in an interview.

Comment: Wow - 4 close votes and 2 down votes!  I thought "Questions on the following topics are welcomed here: Word choice and usage".  I appreciate @Yosef Baskin giving a reason for VTC even though the word in question is not in quotes and is not attributed to the speaker.  I am curious - how is this a bad question for this stack?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this use of "bode" is just bad writing.

The only two words that I've ever heard come after "bode" are "ill" and "well." In the case of "well," I almost always hear it in the negative - i.e., "this does *not* bode well."

edit - I've also heard "bode" at the end of the sentence - e.g., "I'm not sure how this bodes."  In any case, never used as a noun.

Answer (score 0):

The author has confused the verb *bode* with its gerundial noun *boding*.

The verb is:

> Bode = to be a sign of something that will happen in the future, usually something very good or bad:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bode)

Leading to its gerundial noun *boding*, which might justifiably be used in your context as a sign or intimation of future events, but which finds its main use in:

> Foreboding = a feeling that something very bad is going to happen soon
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bode

Google ngram shows *foreboding* to be 100 times the use of *boding*, so it is the best replacement for the author’s erroneous use of *bode*.

Comment: In practical terms, nobody says 'boding'.